# JQuery does not make postback in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

I'm using following JQuery function to make a postback:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click();
```

btnSubmit is an ASP.NET server side button which has a click function defined, postback is performed in Firefox and chrome and my serverside code is executed, but nothing happens in IE, what is going wrong?

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" >

       function uploadTimer() {
           var t = setTimeout("uploadTimer()", 100);
           var value = $("#FileUpload1").val();
           if (value != '') {
               $("#btnSubmit").click();
           }
       }
```

....

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OpenFileUpload() {
        $("#FileUpload1").click();
        uploadTimer();
    }
</script>
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="UploadFileToServer" style="display:none;" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" title="upload file" style="color:Black;" onclick="OpenFileUpload()">upload file</a> <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" Visible="false"/>
```

Comment: Are any parent of this button disabled?

Comment: no, this button is in my form, it works fine in Firefox and chrome

Comment: What version of IE? And could you provide the html of the button?

Comment: Can you post the full (generated) HTML?
Do you get a JS error/warning in IE? Does the console in Chrome or Firefox give any warnings/errors? You could install IE Developer Tools  to check for errors.

Comment: IE doesn't give me any error, how can I click a button in client side in IE? is there any other way?

Comment: Your code doesn't have a definition of `UploadFileToServer`

Comment: it is my server side function which is not executed at all